# Is it possible to implement a protocol type variable with a concrete class in Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

Is it possible to implement a protocol type `var` with a concrete class which implements this protocol?

Does that sound confusing? Here is an example :-)

```
// A protocol requires some var. And an implementation of this class
protocol SomethingProtocol {
    var something: String { get }
}

class SomethingConcrete: SomethingProtocol {
    var something: String { "something" }
    var someOther: String { "something else" }
}


// A protocol which requires someValue of protocol type SomethingProtocol
protocol EntityProtocol {
    var someValue: SomethingProtocol { get }
}


// Implementation of EntityProtocol
class ConcreteEntiy: EntityProtocol {
    // DOES NOT WORK:
    // Implementing the var someValue of required typ SomethingProtocol
    // using its implementation SomethingConcret 
    //       
    // Error: Type 'ConcretEntiy' does not conform to protocol 'EntityProtocol'
    var someValue: SomethingConcrete = SomethingConcrete()



    // DOES WORK:
    // Implementation as SomethingProtocol as required by EntityProtocol
    // but no access to others values of SomethingConcret
    var someValue: SomethingProtocol = SomethingConcrete()
    
    
    // Error: Value of type 'SomethingProtocol' has no member 'somethingElse'
    let otherValue = someValue.somethingElse
}
```

- `EntityProtocol` requires a `var someValue` of protocol type `SomethingProtocol`
- `SomethingConcrete` implements `SomethingProtocol` and thus is of type `SomethingProtocol`
- `ConcreteClass` implements `EntityProtocol` and thus needs a `var someValue` of protocol type `SomethingProtocol`

Why is it not possible to full fill the requirement of `EntityProtocol` by providing a `var someValue` of type `SomethingConcrete`?

Comment: Your code is logically ok but with some syntax errors as I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requiring the class conforming to `EntityProtocol` to have a property holding `SomethingProtocol`, & not any object conforming to that protocol.

That's why generics exist, when using `associatedtype` you're first implementation works because you're setting the type of `someValue` to be whatever you say it is that conforms to `SomethingProtocol`(i.e: `SomethingConcret`). Hence it's not set like your attempt, it is inferred.

```
// A protocol requires some var. And an implementation of this class
protocol SomethingProtocol {
    var something: String { get }
}

class SomethingConcret: SomethingProtocol {
    var something: String { "something" }
    var someOther: String { "something else" }
}


// A protocol which requires someValue conforming to the type SomethingProtocol
protocol EntityProtocol {
    associatedtype SomeValue: SomethingProtocol
    var someValue: SomeValue { get }
}


// Implementation of EntityProtocol
class ConcretEntiy: EntityProtocol {
    // WORKS:
    // Implementing the var someValue of required type SomethingProtocol
    // using its implementation SomethingConcret
   // has access to others values of SomethingConcret
    var someValue: SomethingConcret = SomethingConcret()



    // ALSO WORKS:
    // Implementation as SomethingProtocol as required by EntityProtocol
    // but no access to others values of SomethingConcret
    var someValue: SomethingProtocol = SomethingConcret()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntax error where you wrote extra `=`:

```
var someOther: String { "something else" }
```

2. You **can** assign a conformed concrete to an abstracted `var`:

```
var someValue: SomethingProtocol = SomethingConcret()
```

3. You can **not** access concrete's property from an abstracted `var`. You may want to cast it first:

```
var otherValue: String? { (someValue as? SomethingConcret)?.someOther
```

---

#### Full working demo code (typos and syntax errors fixed)

```
protocol SomethingProtocol {
    var something: String { get }
}

class SomethingConcrete: SomethingProtocol {
    var something: String { "something" }
    var someOther: String { "something else" }
}

protocol EntityProtocol {
    var someValue: SomethingProtocol { get }
}

class ConcreteEntity: EntityProtocol {
    var someValue: SomethingProtocol = SomethingConcrete()
    var otherValue: String? { (someValue as? SomethingConcrete)?.someOther }
}
```